# Wrap element with another div with class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I've browsed around a lot looking for an answer, but I couldn't find anything that meets what I'm looking for.

So I'm editing a forum, that's very locked in terms of adding new css classes to customize the look. So, I want to set it so, I can add a div class before the fixed class.

Example of the fixed class:

```
<div class="titlemedium"> </div>
```

What I'm trying to do using Jquery:

```
<div class="divthatcomesbefore"> <div class="titlemedium"> </div> </div>
```

Basically, I want the *divthatcomesbefore* to auto wrap around the **titlemedium** using JS, and I have no idea how to do it. Please help.

This is the script I tried to write, needless to say, it didn't work.

`<script> $(".divthatcomesbefore").before('<div class="titlemedium"></div>'); </script>`

Comment: You are probably looking for `.wrap()` 
 https://api.jquery.com/wrap/ since the div should be wrapped around the target div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [jQuery's .wrap() method](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```js
$(".titlemedium").wrap(`<div class="divthatcomesbefore" />`);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}

.titlemedium {
  background: gold;
}

.divthatcomesbefore {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="titlemedium"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or in plain JavaScript:

```js
// DOM utility functions:
const els = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelectorAll(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Task:
els(".titlemedium").forEach((elTitleMedium) => {
  const elWrapper = elNew("div", {className: "divthatcomesbefore"});
  elTitleMedium.replaceWith(elWrapper);
  elWrapper.append(elTitleMedium);
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 1rem;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}

.titlemedium {
  background: gold;
}

.divthatcomesbefore {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="titlemedium"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```js
const titlemedium = document.querySelector('.titlemedium');
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.className = 'divthatcomesbefore';
titlemedium.replaceWith(wrapper);
wrapper.appendChild(titlemedium);
```

```css
.titlemedium {
  border: 10px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.divthatcomesbefore {
  border: 10px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="titlemedium"></div>
```